# Performance - What option do you prefer?

Tags: javascript, arrays, switch-statement

In my little project I made two options how a switch could work like:

```
switch (_toler) {
    case '20': var kto='M'; break;      
    case '10': kto='k / K'; break;      
    case '5': kto='J'; break;       
    case '2': kto='G'; break;       
    case '1': kto='F'; break;
    case '0.5': kto='D'; break;
    case '0.25': kto='C'; break;
    case '0.1': kto='B'; break;     
    case '0': default: kto='/'; break;
}
```

and:

```
var wert=["20","10","5","2","1","0.5","0.25","0.1","0"];
var kurz=["M","k / K","J","G","F","D","C","B","/"];
for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
    if (_toler==wert[i]) {kto=kurz[i]}
}
```

Which one would you prefer? I do'nt know whats better, because the second option is less code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are *mapping* `_toler` values to `kto` values, use a map - which in JS is an object.

```
var map = {
    '20': 'M',
    '10': 'k / K',
    '5' : 'J',
    '2' : 'G',
    '1' : 'F',
    '0.5' : 'D',
    '0.25' : 'C',
    '0.1' : 'B',
    '0' : '/'
};
kto = map[_toler];
```

Not only is this by far the best option performance-wise (due to it being reduced to a simple property lookup), it's also much easier to read and maintain if you ever need to change, add or remove mappings.

Answer (score 0):

Given the small number of cases, any performance difference would be negligible, so from a code readability standpoint a for loop would be better.

If you are still concerned with performance than  than a switch is faster in that situation, because a loop would check the end condition several times, and a switch -- only once. This is called `loop unrolling`, and optimising compilers largely do it on their own

Answer (score 0):

You're getting some close votes because you asked "which one would you prefer?" I think your question is valid enough, but you should phrase it as "what are the pros and cons of these options?"

You actually have one other option that isn't even in your list:

```
var wert = [/* stuff */];
var kurz = [/* stuff */];

kto = kurz[wert.indexOf(__toler)] || kurz[0];
```

What this code does is gets the `indexOf()` `__toler` which will either be the index, or will be `-1`. If it is `-1`, then `kurz[-1]` will be `undefined`, which will then fall back to your `kurz[0]` default case. This is the most compact. This approach is fully superior to your version with the loop (though it's Big-O is still about the same).

The benefit of this is it makes it easier to have significantly large lists and lets you modify it at run-time quite easily.

The cons to this is it can be a little tricky to understand if you aren't familiar with the pattern.

The switch pattern is much simpler to read and obvious what it is doing. The con is it can be a lot of code and has a lot of redundant-ness (`kto=`).

In general, the first is going to be preferable when you are just doing the same thing with the value.